# Копирование из одной книги в другую со сдвигом (offset), Динамический offset

Tags: vba

помогите разобраться. Есть две книги 1(основная) и 2. Надо во 2 книге найти  какое - то слово, которое есть в книге 1, выделить его,сдвинуться на определенное количество ячеек в сторону(сдвиг должен указывать сам пользователь) после чего скопировать это значение и перенести его в первую книгу тоже со сдвигом (офсетом) который задается пользователем. Мой макрос в общую (1 книгу) вставляет правильно, но копирует не правильно, он копирует (во второй книге) по адресу ячейки которая находиться в общей(1) книге. Например если имя "Иван" в 1 книге находиться по адресу А1, а во второй книге по адресу А1 будет "Костя", а "Иван" будет по адресу А46, он мне скопирует "Костя" и вставит в 1 книгу в А1. Помогите допилить его, что бы правильно копировалось.Тоесть я хочу, что бы можно было копировать любую информацию, но что бы офсет запрашивался у пользователя, а не редактировать через код. Постарался максимально понятно объяснить задумку.
`Sub Копирование()
Dim Searching As Range
File = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    ("Книга что ищем и куда потом копируем (*.xls*),*.xls*", False)
     Workbooks.Open File
   Firstbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name ' присваивает переменной книгу из которой берем
Set Firstcopy = Application.InputBox("Укажите ЧТО искать:", "Запрос данных", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Set Firstpaste = Application.InputBox("Укажите куда вставлять результат, только одну ячейку:", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
File2 = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    ("Книга откуда копируем значение (*.xls*),*.xls*", False)
Workbooks.Open File2
Secondbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set Secondcopy = Application.InputBox("Укажите ЧТО искать ВСЕ :", "Запрос данных", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Set Secondpaste = Application.InputBox("Ячейка с первым копируемым значением, только одна:", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    For k = 1 To 65
Windows(Secondbook).Activate
    Set Searching = Secondcopy.Find(What:=Firstcopy(k), MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Searching Is Nothing Then
    Else:
    Secondpaste.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(k - 1).Copy ' сдвиг для копирования. Берет номер ячейки с первого файла, копирует не правильно.
   Windows(Firstbook).Activate
   Set Searching = Firstcopy.Find(What:=Firstcopy(k), MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Firstpaste.Select ' сдвиг для вставки
    ActiveCell.Offset(k - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False ' сдвиг для вставки. Вставка работает правильно, с нее берется копирование.
        End If
    Windows(Secondbook).Activate
Next k
End Sub`

Comment: Найти какое-то слово - но в коде просите указать ячейку ('Type:=8')... Зачем сдвигать перед копированием? В чем смысл этих манипуляций? Желательно описывать не придуманный путь решения, а саму задачу..// 
 В 'Offset' нужно указывать два направления. Ошибки при закрытии диалогов. Выделять для копирования/вставки не обязательно.

Comment: Есть два файла 1 и 2. В них есть (для примера) названия групп в ячейке А1, А2, А3 и т.д и в ячейке F1, F2, F3 и т.д есть их альбомы. В 1 файле есть только названия групп, в файле №2 есть и альбомы и группы. Надо в файле 2 найти группу, скопировать ее альбом. Ячейка запрашивается, что бы не лезть в код для правки сдвига, потому что он меняется. Вот сюда сбрасывал файлы чисто для большего понимания задачи https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=1&TID=109707&TITLE_SEO=109707-kopirovanie-iz-odnoy-knigi-v-druguyu-so-sdvigom-_offset_-vba-poisk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Определил адрес первой ячейки для копирования Row и Column и такое же для первой ячейки для вставки и через систему координат отнял их и получил адрес для вставки.

`Sub Копирование()
Dim Searching As Range
File = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    ("Книга что ищем и куда потом копируем (*.xls*),*.xls*", False)
     Workbooks.Open File
   Firstbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set Firstcopy = Application.InputBox("Укажите ЧТО искать:", "Запрос данных", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Set Firstpaste = Application.InputBox("Укажите куда вставлять результат, только одну ячейку:", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
File2 = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    ("Книга откуда копируем значение (*.xls*),*.xls*", False)
Workbooks.Open File2
Secondbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set Secondcopy = Application.InputBox("Укажите ЧТО искать ВСЕ :", "Запрос данных", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Set Secondpaste = Application.InputBox("Ячейка с первым копируемым значением, только одна:", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    For k = 1 To 65
Windows(Secondbook).Activate
    Set Searching = Secondcopy.Find(What:=Firstcopy(k), MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Searching Is Nothing Then
    Else: Searching.Select
    r = Searching.Row 'адрес ячейки поиска
    Secondpaste.Select
    o = ActiveCell.Row 'адрес ячейки копирования
    ActiveCell.Offset(r - o).Copy ' сдвиг для копирования.
   Windows(Firstbook).Activate
   Set Searching = Firstcopy.Find(What:=Firstcopy(k), MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Firstpaste.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(k - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False ' сдвиг для вставки.
        End If
    Windows(Secondbook).Activate
Next k
End Sub`

Comment: Покажите. Останется другим в помощь

Comment: добавил, спасибо, что откликнулись

Answer (score 0):

Разместить код в общем модуле. Файл можно сохранить как надстройку.

Пользователь выбирает файлы, указывает в них по две ячейки (для определения столбцов). При необходимости можно дописать автоопределение листов и не указывать их имена в коде.

```
Option Explicit

Dim sFName As String

' выбор файла'
Sub ChoiceOfFile()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path

        If .Show = False Then
            MsgBox "Файл не выбран!", 48, "Ошибка": End
        Else
            sFName = .SelectedItems(1) ' путь в переменную'
        End If
    End With
End Sub

' функция выбора столбца'
Function fColumn_(sStr As String) As Long
Dim lClmn As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    lClmn = Application.InputBox(sStr, Type:=8).Column
    If Err Then MsgBox "Не выбрана ячейка, работа остановлена", 64, "ОШИБКА": End
    fColumn_ = lClmn
End Function

' основная прцедура'
Sub CopyData_()
Dim aData(), aRes(), aFind()
Dim wBook As Workbook
Dim lFind As Long, lCopy As Long, lData As Long, lPaste As Long
Dim lRw As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' отключаем лишние вопросы'

    MsgBox "Укажите книгу-источник", 64, "": Call ChoiceOfFile ' указываем книгу'
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFName) ' открывем книгу'

    lFind = fColumn_("Выделить ячейку столбца для поиска")
    lCopy = fColumn_("Выделить ячейку столбца для копирования")

    With wBook
        With .Worksheets("отсюда") ' здесь имя нужного листа'
            lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count: If lRw < 2 Then GoTo err_ ' выход, если нет данных'
            aFind = .Cells(1, lFind).Resize(lRw, lCopy - lFind + 1).Value ' данные источника в массив'
        End With

        .Close ' книга уже не нужна, закрываем'
    End With

    MsgBox "Укажите книгу-приемник", 64, "": Call ChoiceOfFile
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFName)

    lData = fColumn_("Выделить ячейку столбца для сравнения")
    lPaste = fColumn_("Выделить ячейку столбца для вставки")

    With wBook.Worksheets("сюда")
        lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count: If lRw < 2 Then GoTo err_
        aData = .Cells(1, lData).Resize(lRw, 1).Value ' данные столбца в массив'
    End With

    ReDim aRes(1 To lRw, 1 To 1) ' размерность массива для результата'

    For i = 2 To lRw ' по данным столбца пфайла-приемника'
        k = 1 ' первую строку не будем просматривать - там шапка'

        Do ' в цикле ищем совпадение и записываем найденное в массиив результата'
            k = k + 1
            If aData(i, 1) = aFind(k, 1) Then aRes(i, 1) = aFind(k, UBound(aFind, 2))
        Loop Until aRes(i, 1) <> Empty Or k = UBound(aFind) ' уловия выхода из цикла'
    Next i

    wBook.Worksheets("сюда").Cells(1, lPaste).Resize(lRw, 1).Value = aRes ' результат на лист'
err_:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set wBook = Nothing ' освобождаем память'
End Sub
```

Comment: Мне не подходит. Проблема в том, что если все прописывать руками, offset, и мой код работает. Мне именно через MsgBox надо и я не знаю как это сделать. В этом мне нужна помощь, именно с MsgBox'ом. Select указаны для прощего отслеживания кода через F8.

Comment: >>*Select указаны для прощего отслеживания кода через F8* -  Непонятно и неубедительно. Работа с объектами очень сильно замедляет выполнение кода, а *Select* - выделение объекта

Comment: Надеялся, что подставить InputBox сможете... Заменил код в ответе